# Magento 2 can't deploy : full red error

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy

(Using putty). I can't deploy my magento 2 anymore...
Tried chmod, tried setup upgrade..

Any idea or tips will be much appreciated.

```
   #0 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Deployment/Version.php(56): Magento\Framework\App\View\Deployment\Version->readValue('production')
#1 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Url/Plugin/Signature.php(87): Magento\Framework\App\View\Deployment\Version->getValue()
#2 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Url/Plugin/Signature.php(65): Magento\Theme\Model\Url\Plugin\Signature->renderUrlSignature()
#3 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Theme\Model\Url\Plugin\Signature->afterGetBaseUrl(Object(Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor), 'https://...', 'static', false)
#4 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('static', false)
#5 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/Store/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getBaseUrl', Array, Array)
#6 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/framework/Url.php(482): Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor->getBaseUrl('static', false)
#7 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Repository.php(273): Magento\Framework\Url->getBaseUrl(Array)
#8 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Repository.php(222): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository->getFallbackContext('static', NULL, 'frontend', 'Magento/blank', 'fr_FR')
#9 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployStaticFile.php(87): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository->createAsset('js/responsive.j...', Array)
#10 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(189): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticFile->deployFile('js/responsive.j...', Array)
#11 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(136): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->processFile(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\PackageFile), Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
#12 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(107): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deployEmulated(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array, false)
#13 [internal function]: Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->Magento\Deploy\Service\{closure}()
#14 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php(186): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#15 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(108): Magento\Framework\App\State->emulateAreaCode('frontend', Object(Closure))
#16 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(281): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deploy(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array)
#17 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(200): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->execute(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
#18 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(162): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->assertAndExecute('frontend/Magent...', Array, Array)
#19 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Strategy/QuickDeploy.php(76): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->process()
#20 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployStaticContent.php(109): Magento\Deploy\Strategy\QuickDeploy->deploy(Array)
#21 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DeployStaticContentCommand.php(140): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticContent->deploy(Array)
#22 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(245): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#23 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(835): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#24 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(185): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#25 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(104): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#26 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(117): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#27 /var/www/clients/client0/web6/web/boutique/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#28 {main}
```

Comment: try removing contents of `generated/code` and `generated/metadata`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I just did it, same error.

Comment: Is developer mode set? if no first try to set developer mode and run deployment. You may get some more information.

Comment: I tried switch in dev mode. Then static content deploy. It works only in dev mode..